# How can I find the price of a product if the manufacturer doesn't show it on their website?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, equipment-selection

I need to buy a particular brand and model of stepper motor and I have found the product [on the manufacturer's web catalog](http://motion.schneider-electric.com/products/mdrive/mdrive_plus_motion_control.php?nema=17), but with no price listed.

1. How can I find the price of device? I tried writing to the manufacturer but they haven't responded.
2. Why has the manufacturer hidden the price?

Comment: Maker's website should list distributors in different countries. Select your country from the list on the "Contacts" page. Contact them. By phone if necessary, you may need to speak to a human being. But if you need less than a thousand, be prepared to be ignored. You may have to redesign using a more widely available part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In industry, an equipment manufacturer hardly ever sells directly to the end user. They supply distributors in bulk at a negotiated price for each shipment of however many units the distributor orders. The price-per-unit varies accordingly, so there's no point in listing it the way you would for retail products.

If you only need a single unit of a product, generally the manufacturer is not going to want to do business with you. They produce many units at a time, as required to supply their distributor(s), in order to use their facilities and personnel efficiently.

What you need to do is find a distributor or wholesaler who carries that manufacturer's products and is willing to sell directly to you (retail business). [Grainger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._W._Grainger) is one example of a company that does this, though you may have to work for a company that has a business account with them in order to just walk in and order a single item.

You can usually find the contact information for a local or regional distributor on the company's web site or in their catalog, provided they do business in your area. Sometimes, especially when dealing with a foreign supplier, they won't have an existing business relationship with anyone in your region, and then you may need to look for an alternative product or work with a foreign distributor as well, which can be a real headache for just one piece of equipment.